# How does --network=host generate different HTTP requests then rootless networking?

Tags: networking, ipv6, resolution, podman, ipv4

I have two commands, one of them with

```bash
# RESOLVES TO IPV6
podman run --network=host ...
```

And one of them,

```bash
# RESOLVES TO IPV4
podman run --network=slirp4netns ...
```

Is there anyway to ensure both of these resolve to the same address? For some reason the ipv6 resolution isn't blacklisted, the ipv4 resolution is blacklisted.

This can be confirmed if I specify `wget -4` and `wget -6`. I find that for both with `-6` the requests work and come back with a response; the `-4` returns HTTP 403 Forbidden -- it's blacklisted. That tells me this is predominately a resolver problem however if I run,

```bash
podman run -ti --network=slirp4netns alpine:3 nslookup rr4.sn-q4flrnsk.googlevideo.com.
podman run -ti --network=host alpine:3 nslookup rr4.sn-q4flrnsk.googlevideo.com.
```

The non-authoritative answers that come back are the same.

```
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   rr4.sn-q4flrnsk.googlevideo.com
Address: 2607:f8b0:4000:4::9

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   rr4.sn-q4flrnsk.googlevideo.com
Address: 173.194.24.137
```

But if I run,

```bash
podman run -ti --network=slirp4netns alpine:3 ping -w1 rr4.sn-q4flrnsk.googlevideo.com.
podman run -ti --network=host alpine:3 ping -w1 rr4.sn-q4flrnsk.googlevideo.com.
```

I can again see that the slirp4netns chooses ipv4 and host chooses ipv6,

```
$ podman run -ti --network=slirp4netns alpine:3 ping -w1 rr4.sn-q4flrnsk.googlevideo.com.

PING rr4.sn-q4flrnsk.googlevideo.com. (173.194.24.137): 56 data bytes

$ podman run -ti --network=host alpine:3 ping -w1 rr4.sn-q4flrnsk.googlevideo.com.

PING rr4.sn-q4flrnsk.googlevideo.com. (2607:f8b0:4000:4::9): 56 data bytes
```

Help this make sense to me, why does `--network=host` resolve to ipv6 by default and not `--network=slirp4netns`?